# Can both os.DirEntry.is_dir() and os.DirEntry.is_file() return False for an object in os.scandir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making an event handler similar to `os.system("dir")` and it would be nice to know. I'm not sure what the object could be, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Did you check in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_dir)? As their names suggest, they return `True` if the entry is a dir/file, and `False` otherwise...

Comment: `os.is_dir` and `os.is_file` don't exist. There are no such functions. (Tomerikoo's link is for `os.DirEntry.is_dir`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica My bad! Thanks for the correction!!!

Comment: Probably OP meant the more commonly known `os.path.isdir` and `os.path.isfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible for both `os.DirEntry.is_dir` and `os.DirEntry.is_file` to return False: `is_dir()` is for directories (which is obvious) but `is_file()` is only for so-called [regular files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISREG).

This means it can return `False` for something which is not a directory, like devices, pipes, ... for instance on unices most of `/dev` is neither a file nor a directory. I'm less sure about windows, but it probably has such concepts e.g. the "magic" reserved names like `CON` or `PRN` or `LPT1` (though I guess those wouldn't show up in a scandir).